# Compounded probability with 3 dices

Tags: probability-theory

If a dice is rolled 1 time,the probability of getting a 4 is 1/6.what is the probability of getting exactly  4 once if the die is rolled thrice

Answer (score 1):

Define rolling a $4$ as a success, this is a binomial distribution with $n=3$ and $p = \frac16$.

$$X \sim Bin(3, \frac16)$$ where $X$ denotes the number of $4$.

$$P(X=1)= 3 \left(\frac16 \right)\left(\frac56\right)^2$$

Comment: So what is the probability

Comment: Oh sorry!! I had not seen the entire answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is (it's very, very simple):

The probability of not getting a four on the first roll is $5/6$

If there are two attempts/rolls, it's gonna be $(5/6)^2$

And not getting a four with three attempts/rolls is $(5/6)^3$

Therefore, the probability of getting a four at least once is $1-(5/6)^3≈0.42$

Comment: Can't it be like.... if probability of getting a 4 is 1/6 then probability of getting a 4 in three times rolling is(1/6)^3

Comment: Yes if you want to get a four on each of the three rolls, then it's (1/6)^3. And if you want to get a four ONLY EXACTLY once (and not twice or three times) with three rolls it’s been answered by Siong Thye Goh